# Tipo de divisa al pagar

Tags: mercadopago

Buenos dias, hace unos dias pregunte sobre si era posible pagar con mercado pago entre diferentes paises, se que no es posible a la fecha y la solucion que implemente fue crear 2 aplicación en mercado pago de la misma, una para Chile y otra para Argentina y que dependiendo de donde se utilice es la aplicación de MP que voy a utilizar.
Ahora, si están utilizando la aplicación que cree para Chile, MP automáticamente reconoce que la divisa a usar es Pesos Chilenos? Si el mismo proyecto, pero utilizado desde Argentina y apuntando a la aplicación de MP de Argentina este reconoce el monto ingresado es en Pesos Argentinos?
Hace falta ingresar el tipo de divisa o esto se interpreta automáticamente dependiendo del país en el que este creada la aplicación de MP?
Saludos y Gracias por leer!

Answer (score 1):

Si no defines en el request JSON el tipo de divisa, usara por defecto el del pais, esto lo intuye a partir del access_token, el posee identificadores de pais.